# sass import variable in import file

Tags: sass

I try to make different **config** files (for different colors) and use the variables in another file I import **basic.scss**, Im going to make multiple app.scss files like app1.scss and app2.scss which use different config files with different colors.

My config1.scss

```
$primary-color : #6a7dcc;
$primary-font-color: #ccc;
```

my basic.scss

```
body {
  background-color: $primary-color;
  color: $primary-font-color;
}
```

my app1.scss

```
@import "config2.scss";
@import "basic.scss";
```

This gives me the error:

> Error: Undefined variable: "$primary-color". on line 2 of
>   app/css/basic.sc

How can I use imported variables in other imported files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
@import "_config2";
@import "_basic";
```

Comment: From the SASS guide:

"You can create partial Sass files that contain little snippets of CSS that you can include in other Sass files. This is a great way to modularize your CSS and help keep things easier to maintain. A partial is simply a Sass file named with a leading underscore. You might name it something like _partial.scss. The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file. Sass partials are used with the @import directive."

Answer (score 0):

File Config1.scss is having variable $primary-color and your are importing config2.scss (which is not having variable $primary-color) in your app1.scss, i think that is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a `config1` and `config2`. Unless that is a typo, once you change your `@import config2.scss` to `@import config1.scss` it should work.

Tl;dr you arent importing the file where the variables were declared. Do that and it should work.

Comment: @Pyth, thats not what im trying, i want the same classes but with different values, so i import two different files with different values. to generate two different files with the same classes but different propertys. WimMertens answer worked.